# Javascript - Javascript functions run before the AngularJS loading the HTML elements, so the functions do not get the elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I want to bind the AddEventListener pure javascript method on DOM elements.
But I use AngularJS which include a html file, and this including runs after the AddEventListner functions are binded to the DOM. So the pure JavaScript does not find the DOMs.
I am new in the pure JS word. I used the jQuery, but in this project I want to use only AngularJS and pure JS. :)

This code is included (ng-include) by the AngularJS

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-0 padding-left-right-0">
                <span class="game game-home" ng-show='gameEvent.game_home > 0' ng-click="addToSlip(gameEvent.id, gameEvent.name, gameEvent.game_home, 'H', gameEvent.number)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <span class="slip-game-event-add-button">
                        {{ gameEvent.game_home | number:2 }}
                    </span>
                    <span class="badge">{{ gameEvent.taken_home}}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 padding-left-right-0">
                <span class="game game-draw" ng-show='gameEvent.game_draw > 0'ng-click="addToSlip(gameEvent.id, gameEvent.name, gameEvent.game_draw, 'D', gameEvent.number)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <span class="slip-game-event-add-button">
                        {{ gameEvent.game_draw | number:2 }}
                    </span>
                     <span class="badge">{{ gameEvent.taken_draw}}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1 padding-left-right-0">
                <span class="game game-away" ng-show='gameEvent.game_away > 0' ng-click="addToSlip(gameEvent.id, gameEvent.name, gameEvent.game_away, 'V', gameEvent.number)" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <span class="slip-game-event-add-button">
                        {{ gameEvent.game_away | number:2 }}
                    </span>
                    <span class="badge">{{ gameEvent.taken_away}}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

And this is my pure javascript file:

```
'For.the.view';

(function() {
    var gameDom = document.getElementsByClassName("game");

    for (var i=0;i<gameDom.length;i++) {
        gameDom[i].addEventListener('click', clickEventForThis, false);
    };
})();

function clickEventForThis(){
    console.log("hello");
};
```

**Unfortunately this javascript codes run, before the AngularJS loads the HTML file.** So it cannot find any gameDoms...

Yes, the most easiest way is using the "`onclick`" attributate, but it will not be a nice solution, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the angular.ready event:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var gameDom = document.getElementsByClassName("game");

    for (var i=0;i<gameDom.length;i++) {
        gameDom[i].addEventListener('click', clickEventForThis, false);
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. The code still runs before the HTML. I think I forget something.

Comment: That piece of code ensure the code inside run after the DOM is bootstraped, unless you're not sharing something